# Perífrasis de futuro en subjuntivo

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, futuro

No entiendo completamente qué pasa en una frase como

> No duda que vaya a ser investido

(que viene de https://www.diariodeleon.es/articulo/espana/sanchez-duda-vaya-ser-investido-martes-claro-hombre/202001051329591973836.html)

A mi entender se puede sustituir 'no duda' por 'cree', entonces

> ?? Cree que vaya a ser investido

Pues, a mi entender estamos antes una declaración, no antes una no-declaración (ve https://terceragramatica.com/consultorio-el-modo-afecta-al-verbo-que-lo-lleva/) así que me parece el subjuntivo un poco raro aquí.

¿Porque usamos el subjuntivo en esta frase?  ¿Es porqu funciona como una cláusula relativa con 'cuando'?

Similarmente tenemos

> Pone en duda que vaya a existir una bala de plata contra el covid

(https://www.eleconomista.es/internacional/noticias/10703879/08/20/La-OMS-dice-que-los-estudios-de-las-vacunas-COVID-son-esperanzadores-pero-podrian-no-dar-fruto.html)

¿Es que 'duda' convierte la frase en una no-declaración?

Supongo paso por alto lo obvio.  ¡Cualquier consejo agradecido!

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente, "no duda..." usa el subjuntivo porque es negativa, mientras que al reemplazarla por "cree..." que es afirmativa, pasas a usar indicativo.

No encuentro alguna fuente más oficial, pero [aquí](https://espanol.lingolia.com/es/gramatica/tiempos-comparacion/indicativo-subjuntivo) se explica bastante claro:

> **Indicativo**.
> Los tiempos del modo indicativo se emplean en español en los siguientes casos:
>
> - con enunciados que expresan verdad o que describen lo que ocurre de
>   facto;
>   Ejemplo: María se alegra.
> - **después de verbos de habla y
>   pensamiento en su forma afirmativa;
>
>   Ejemplo: Creo que María se alegra.**
> - después de cuando, mientras, hasta que, tan pronto como…, si la acción
>   ya se ha producido o se produce con regularidad;
>   Ejemplo: Esperé hasta que llegaste. Estoy muy a gusto cuando hablo contigo.
> - para describir a alguien o algo en concreto con unas características dadas.
>   Ejemplo:
>   Busco a una persona que habla español. Sé de alguien que habla español
>   y lo estoy buscando.
>
> **Subjuntivo**
> Los tiempos del modo subjuntivo deben emplearse en las
> siguientes situaciones:
>
> - después de ciertas palabras que indican deseo, esperanza, duda o
>   sentimiento;   Ejemplo: Ojalá María se alegre. Quiero que María se
>   alegre.
> - **después de verbos de habla y pensamiento en su forma negativa;
>
>   Ejemplo: No creo que María se alegre.**
> - después de cuando, mientras, hasta que, tan pronto como…, si la acción aún no ha  tenido lugar;
>   Ejemplo: Esperaré hasta que llegues.
> - para describir a alguien o algo
>   que no se conoce y que tiene unas características especiales;
>   Ejemplo:
>   Busco a una persona que hable español. Necesito a una persona
>   cualquiera que hable español.
> - con el imperativo de la 3ª persona del singular y del plural en su
>   forma afirmativa, así como para la forma negativa de todas las
>   personas;
>   Ejemplo: Juegue/Jueguen a la lotería. No juegues con fuego.
> - en expresiones concretas que rigen el subjuntivo;
>   Ejemplo: Cueste lo
>   que cueste. Como tú quieras. Lo que tú decidas.
> - tras ciertas
>   expresiones y verbos que se detallan en las listas que encontrarás en
>   el recuadro.
>   Ejemplo: Llama antes para que no pierdas el tiempo en la
>   sala de espera.

Comment: "Dudar" es distinto: también lleva subjuntivo cuando está en afirmativo: "Dudo que esto acabe pronto". Yo creo que el primer punto de la lista de casos para "Subjuntivo" que citas es más apropiado: "después de ciertas palabras que indican deseo, esperanza, **duda** o sentimiento"...

Comment: @wimi Si, lo que pasa es que en la pregunta está cambiando el verbo (y lo cambia a un "creo" afirmativo). Es verdad que si dudara en afirmativo sería subjuntivo. Le pasa por andar creyendo cosas.